# Set xparse variables to lowercase

Tags: typography, xparse

A while ago, I asked for a method to comfortably define several variables and the best answer came up with `xparse` and its `key`-`value` pairs. I now have two related issues, which I would like to discuss here.

**Note:** It's probably very useful to check [the original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384437/define-variable-without-newcommand) before going on, so you know my `xparse` setup.

---

#### Issue 1

I now tried to use the `\lowercase{}` function on these "variables".

```
\lowercase{\GetInvoiceData{FirstName}}
```

This results in the output `Unknown`, if I just call `\GetInvoiceData{FirstName}`, everything works just fine.

So my question is, how to print the value of an `xparse` key in lowercase.

---

#### Issue 2

*I added the `%` as proposed by Christian Hupfer in the comments, which solves this issue.*

Furthermore I wanted to print my whole name in lowercase letters and joined together (the first name in a thin font, the second name in a bold type) like so:

> john**doe**

My current code looks like this

```
\newcommand{\headertext}[2]
{%
    \color{white}%
    {%
        \Huge{%
            %\lowercase{%
                \textlight{#1}\textbold{#2}%
            %}%
        }%
    }%
}

% later in the code

\headertext{\GetInvoiceData{FirstName}}{\GetInvoiceData{SecondName}}
```

Note that `\textlight{}` and `\textbold{}` only define which font should be used:

```
\newcommand{\textlight}[1]
{%
    % Normally defines another font
    {#1}
}
% Same for \textbold{}
```

As you see, `\lowercase{}` is currently commented out because of the `Unknown`-issue, but the output of this is:

> John **Doe**

So the font selection works well, but why is there a space between the two values? And how can I get rid of it?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Variables Configuration
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \prop_new:N \g_invoice_prop
    
    \cs_new:Nn \invoice_store_property:nn {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_invoice_prop {#1} {#2}
    }
    
    %Defining key-value interface
    \keys_define:nn {invoice} {
        FirstName       .code:n = {\invoice_store_property:nn {FirstName}{#1} },
        LastName        .code:n = {\invoice_store_property:nn {LastName}{#1} },
    }
      
    \NewDocumentCommand{\StoreInvoiceData}{+m}{
        \prop_gclear:N \g_invoice_prop% Clearing the property list
        % Set the keys
        \keys_set:nn {invoice}{#1}
    }
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{\GetInvoiceData}{m}{
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_invoice_prop {#1} 
        {% True
            \prop_item:Nn \g_invoice_prop {#1}% Extract the key #1 from the property list
        }{% False
            Unknown
        }
    }

    % Check if the field is given and execute #2 for true case, otherwise #3
    \NewDocumentCommand{\IfInvoiceFieldGivenTF}{m+m+m}{%
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_invoice_prop {
            #1% Check to check
        }{% True #2
            #2
        }{% False
            #3
        }
    }% End of \IfInVoiceFieldGivenT
    
    % Do something only if #1 is given 
    \NewDocumentCommand{\IfInvoiceFieldGivenT}{m+m}{%
        \prop_if_in:NnT \g_invoice_prop {
            #1% Check to check
        }{% True #2
            #2
        }%
    }% End of \IfInVoiceFieldGivenT

\ExplSyntaxOff

\StoreInvoiceData{
    FirstName   =   {John},
    LastName    =   {Doe},
}



%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Font Configuration
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\textlight}[1]
{%
    % Normally defines another font
    {#1}%
}

\newcommand{\textbold}[1]
{%
    % Normally defines another font
    {\bfseries#1}%
}

\newcommand{\headertext}[2]
    {%
        \color{black}
        {%
            \Huge{%
                \lowercase{%
                    \textlight{#1}\textbold{#2}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
\begin{document}
    \headertext{\GetInvoiceData{FirstName}}{\GetInvoiceData{LastName}}
\end{document}
```

Comment out `\lowercase{}` and you'll see, that the name is printed correctly. When using the function, it only prints `Unknown`.

Comment: I suspect a spurious space due to your 'strange' command definitions, right after `\newcommand{\headertext}[2]{` there should be a `%` character, as well as for `\textlight` definition. I am the author of the linked answer, but I can't make a test for your setup right now because I have no idea what `\Ralewaylight` does...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I edited the question and included the definition of `\RalewayLight`.

Comment: PS: The issue with the space could be solved by the `%`. Thanks for that!

Comment: Well, nobody can really use the fragments here...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're absolutely right! I now added an MWE.

Comment: `\lowercase{\GetInvoiceData{FirstName}}` is `\GetInvoiceData{firstname}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh okay, that explains why the key is not defined!

Comment: unrelated but your `\headertext` definition is missing lots of `%` at ends of lines and will add 5 space tokens after the text

Comment: `\Huge` doesn't take an argument. `\color` takes only one.